# Bought something in September but didn't buy anything in October

Tags: mysql

I have this table. I need help with a query that only displays customer IDs that bought something in September but didn't buy anything in October.

```
customer_id     purchase_item       qty     purchase_date
-----------     -------------       ---     -------------
  5415151       desk organizer       1      9/5/2015
  5415151       desk lamp            1      9/5/2015
  7884195       pen holder           8      9/7/2015
  7894152       flash drive          10     9/19/2015
  5987412       universal charger    2      9/28/2015
  1264879       desk fan             20     10/7/2015
  5415151       filing cabinet       5      10/10/2015
  7894152       flash drive          5      10/10/2015
```

... and this is what I want to see:

```
  user_id     
  -------    
  7894152     
  5987412
```

Comment: I would shoot for a helper table (12 rows per year, for instance 9/1/2015 is 1 row). Use that in a left join, it being on left. The left join is on month= and year=  ... so that is why one only needs 1 row per month. So in the results, the user who has a null for sum gets an email: "hey where's the love, why not buying anymore"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.customer_id
FROM customer_table T1
   LEFT JOIN customer_table T2 ON T1.customer_id = T2.customer_id AND 
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(T1.purchase_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 9 AND
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(T2.purchase_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 10
WHERE T2.customer_id IS NULL AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(T1.purchase_date, '%m/%d/%Y')) = 9
```

Try DEMO [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44b57/4) , it will work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for this. I'm running your suggestion now. It'll take a while for the results to show themselves. I'll get back to you when I got it.

Comment: I have edited the query(there was a problem with previous query)..i have added SQL Fiddle demo

Comment: use BETWEEN instead of MONTH(STR_TO_DATE - that way the query will be much faster in case if index on purchase_date exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this query like that :-

```
SELECT customer_id,
group_concat(month((str_to_date(purchase_date,'%m/%d/%y')))) as date1
FROM `customer` group by customer_id 
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('9',date1) >0 and FIND_IN_SET('10',date1) =0
```

[Try demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7c58/1)